# How to create multi filter in react js

Tags: reactjs, filter

I easily can make single filtering but when there are multiple criteria to filter by that is more difficult for me.

1) the default should be: show all,

2) I have an object that has category, time, and size for a filter,

3) When there are no matching criteria, should have some p/div that shows that no filters are matching

4) as mentioned earlier I need to filter by category time and size one by one (single filter) or at the same time (multi-filter) depending on each other.

5) the filters should be represented by buttons and for example, for the category, there should be 4 buttons representing each category, for the size also 4 buttons from `2-4`, `4-8`, `8-16` and `16-32`, for the time there should be also 4 buttons `5-20`, `20-40`, `40-60`, `60+` and reset all of course.

Example (id:7 no category):

```
[ 

 { "id": "0",
   "category": "Racing",
    "size": "16-32",
    "time": "30min" } ,


 { "id": "1",
   "category": "FPS",
    "size": "16-32",
    "time": "20min" } , 

{ "id": "2",
   "category": "RTS",
    "size": "10-12",
    "time": "40min" } , 

{ "id": "3",
   "category": "RTS",
    "size": "8-16",
    "time": "60min" } , 

{ "id": "4",
   "category": "RTS",
    "size": "2-4",
    "time": "10min" } , 

{ "id": "5",
   "category": "Racing",
    "size": "4-8",
    "time": "5min" } , 

{ "id": "6",
   "category": "Racing",
    "size": "4-8",
    "time": "15min" } , 

{ "id": "7",
   "category": "",
    "size": "2",
    "time": "20min" } , 

{ "id": "8",
   "category": "Third Person",
    "size": "2-4",
    "time": "70min" } ,

{ "id": "9",
   "category": "Racing",
    "size": "1",
    "time": "1min" } ,

]
```